# Access Fragment View From MyClass

Tags: android, view

Let's say i have a class called MyClass.java, and Fragment called MyFragment, MyFragment has views such as, spinners, editText.

The Question is How can i access these views from MyClass,

i have tried some thing like this.

```
public class MyClass{
private EditText mEditText ;
public MyClass(EditText text) {
    mEditText = text;
}
}
```

i creaded an object on the fragment yet still have an error:

```
04-16 14:38:59.038: E/AndroidRuntime(25902): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to access the widgets in your fragment from a totally independent class, you can declare them as public static objects, but that can create problems

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks more to java problems rather then android problems.

Just passing fragment object to MyClass. For instance,

```
public class MyClass{
private EditText mEditText ;
private Fragment mFragment;
public MyClass(EditText text, Fragment frag) {
    mEditText = text;
    mFragment = frag;

    // Then you can access the view in your fragment
    // But make sure the fragment already created the view, otherwise you will get null returned
    mFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.myeditview);
}
}
```